# Break a rectangle into randomly shaped polygons

Tags: algorithm, polygon, shapes

Just like the title says, I need to break a rectangle into randomly shaped polygons.

Example, with 7 polygons:

```
+--------+--------+
|\       |   2    |
| \  1   |''--..__|
|  ------|  5     |
| 3  /   \________|
|   /    /\   6   |
|__/ 4  /  \______|
|      /  7       |
+-----+-----------+
```

I don't know if there's an algorithm already out there for this, but I can't seem to get my head around this.

I don't particularly care what language you answer in, but I'll be implementing in Java/Swing.

Comment: I don't think you mean "randomly shaped" polygons; those polygons in your example are not randomly shaped.  Do you mean that you don't care about the shape of the polygons?  That's different from "randomly shaped".

Comment: @McWafflestix: What do you mean by "randomly shaped", then? I mean that if you run this algorithm multiple times, the generated polygons will be different each.

Comment: "random" implies no relation to other members of the set; for a rectangle broken up in the way you indicate, some members have a relationship to other members (for example, a common edge length).

Comment: @McWafflestix: I see what you mean now. I mean random in that they should be vary each time the algorithm is run, but everything should still fit in the original rectangle.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may drop a bunch of random points on the rectangle, and calculate the Voronoi Diagram.

[**Here is a Java/Swing implementation.**](http://read.pudn.com/downloads154/sourcecode/graph/683326/delaunay/DelaunayAp.java__.htm)

I did some samples (but [using Mathematica](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VoronoiDiagram.html), not the above implementation)

[image]

[image]

[image]

HTH!

Comment: +1 for thinking what I was thinking :)  Note that Voronoi pieces are convex whereas the original example had some concave pieces. You could randomly merge a few Voronoi neigbors to get concave ones.

Comment: @celion I think "randomly shaped" is just an intuitive concept ... and the Voronoi diagram provides a nice playground for obtaining weird shapes just removing a few edges. (ups! again thinking the same :D )

Comment: can we define minimum area for each polygon area?

Answer (score 5):

I'd draw a bunch of random lines across the full rectangle and then "split" the lines at each line intersection, so that you basically have some kind of net of lines. Then remove as many random line segments as you like until you reach the desired number of polygons.

Edit: So for your sample it would have been like this after adding the lines:

```
+----+---+----+---+
|\'--.\_/|   /    |
| \    X |''/-..__|
|--\--+-\+-/------|
|___\/___\/_______|
|   /\   /\       |
|__/__\_/|_\______|
| /    X |  \     |
++----+-++---+----+
```

Comment: This reminds me of a 2D version of the [fault algorithm](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/terrain/index.php3?fault).

Comment: The problem I see with this is that it is difficult to determine programmatically which lines to remove. Also, this has the possibility to generate tiny little polygons, which I would like to avoid if at all possible.

Comment: I didn't know the fault algorithm, but yes, is is very similar indeed!

Comment: Austin, the less lines you add the bigger your polygons become. As for which segments to remove, pick them randomly, using a rule set if required (such as only removing lines from polygons touching the border), or pick them by polygon size (pick lines from the smallest touching polygon surface for instance).