# Torn paper effect (break a rectangle into random shapes)

Tags: algorithm, math, svg, graphics

What I'm looking for is this effect illustrated in [this antique question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330524/break-a-rectangle-into-randomly-shaped-polygons):

```
+--------+--------+
|\       |   2    |
| \  1   |''--..__|
|  ------|  5     |
| 3  /   \________|
|   /    /\   6   |
|__/ 4  /  \______|
|      /  7       |
+-----+-----------+
```

The end goal is to make a programatically "torn paper" effect, with similar shapes like this image.

[image: torn white paper]

The Voronoi Diagram suggestions doesn't do exactly what I want, as it doesn't look "organic" and it doesn't generate concave pieces.

The small cuts on each piece I can take care later, for now I'm looking for suggestions on how to do the macro of this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: You *want* concave pieces?  You can fiddle with the distance metric used for the Voronoi diagram.  Or perhaps a Voronoi diagram where you randomly combine adjacent regions.  However, the boundaries are unlikely to be lines.  This might be more appropriate for https://math.stackexchange.com/questions, but you'll have to do a better job of explaining "lines".

Comment: @GordonLinoff: thanks! With the rectangle divided into lines as shown on the ASCII art, I believe it'd be easy to draw "squiggly" over those and get the final effect of the image I posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the image you are showing, the cuts are just made of random noise on top of straight lines. If you remove the noise, you are left with a bunch of straight cuts (8 in this example), and all the pieces are convex. Take the third piece form the left at the very bottom: it looks like a 5-sided (maybe 6-sided) concave piece, but it really is just a 4 sided convex piece. Its top side is very uneven, but it is the result of noise on top of the bottom-most horizontal cut. If that is what you mean by "organic look", then here is what you can do to reproduce it.

First, generate random straight lines, one by one, ideally using blue noise or something similar (so that you are less likely to get lots of tiny pieces next to big ones). Blue noise is often used in space sampling to avoid problems inherent to using white noise or no noise at all (regular patterns).

If you need to get a certain number of pieces at the end, you can easily count them on the fly (and stop at that number), by counting the number of lines each new one intersects. A cut that doesn't intersect any other cut only produces one more piece. For each new intersection, it produces one more: if a cut intersects two previous cuts, then it produces one plus two: three more pieces.

Once you have computed a satisfying set of straight lines, add pink noise to each one. Pink noise (or fractal noise) is used for example in random terrain generation in video games (there is obviously more to it than that, but it is often a main ingredient). Perlin noise is an example of pink noise. This is what will give you the "organic look", at least locally.

This gives you the shape of each cut. One last problem to deal with is at the intersections (including at the borders): because of the irregular shape of cuts, you risk producing tiny pieces where the cuts meet. A way to deal with that is to make each cut one by one, and stop whenever it exits the paper, even if it continues for a tiny bit afterwards. For the first cut, you only need to pay attention at the borders. For the next ones, you also need to pay attention at the intersections with previous cuts.

If you need more information on different noise colors, I can recommend this read: [Noise Functions and Map Generation](https://www.redblobgames.com/articles/noise/introduction.html).

Comment: Thank you very much! After reading your comment it seems so clear that the cuts are just straight lines with added noise. Thanks again!